# Macro that Deletes/Clears contents of table in excel but keep the last three columns

Tags: excel, vba

I currently have a copy/paste macro that looks up a string text within my workbook destination  that opens a source data workbook and copies and pastes back into the workbook destination. I added two pieces in my code that clear the contents and then will delete any rows that have blank cells in the first column. I use this code on numerous workbooks that is able to successfully clear and resize the table I have a copy/paste macro in.

```
    Dim wbSourceData As Workbook
    Dim wbDestination As Workbook
    Dim wsSourceData As Worksheet
    Dim wsDestination As Worksheet
    Dim strFName As String
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim Cl As Long
    Dim Rl As Long
    

    Set wbDestination = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsDestination = wbDestination.Sheets("Data Table")
    
    strFName = wbDestination.Worksheets("Macros").Range("C2").Value
    
    Set wbSourceData = Workbooks.Open(strFName)
    Set wsSourceData = wbSourceData.Worksheets(2)
    
    Set tbl = wsDestination.ListObjects("Data_Table")
    
    tbl.DataBodyRange.ClearContents     'This clears the contents of the table
    
    With wsSourceData
    Cl = .Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Rl = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng1 = .Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(Rl, Cl))
    End With
    
    rng1.Copy
    wsDestination.Range("A4").PasteSpecial xlValues
    
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    wbSourceData.Close SaveChanges:=False
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rng2 = Range("Data_Table[[Names]]").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not rng2 Is Nothing Then
        rng2.Delete Shift:=xlUp                  'This deletes rows with blank cells in the first column
    End If
    
End Sub
```

The name of the tab that the source data is being pasted to is "Data Table".
The name of the table in this sheet is called "Data_Table".
The first column in this table is called "Names".
The name of the tab that the string looks up is called "Macros".

I realized this code will delete all data inside the table, which does not work when there are formulas inside the table that I need to remain. So pretty much I am looking to add to this code a way where the last three columns in this table do not get deleted as they are formulas (columns R-S or 18-20) but still keep the rest of the code in tact as it works well. I am a beginner in VBA so I would appreciate responses in an ELI5 format. Thank you.

Please let me know if you need any clarification of names inside my code.

Comment: One approach would just be to copy column R-S to an empty range, then clear the table content, and then paste it back. Not the most elegant way to do it, but it should work.

Comment: I think I would prefer something more elegant than that

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit more work, but you could also save the data in an array, and then put it back after the clear, instead of copying it to another range in the sheet.
Something along the lines of:

```
Dim tblArray As Variant

tblArray = tbl.ListColumns(18).DataBodyRange.Resize(, 2) 
'An array of the content of column 18, rezsized to 18-19.

tbl.DataBodyRange.ClearContents 'You have this one already ofc

For i = 1 To 2                                      'Columns 1 and 2 (R and S)
    For j = LBound(tblArray) To UBound(tblArray)    'All the rows in the array
        tbl.ListColumns(18).DataBodyRange.Cells(j, i).Value = tblArray(j, i)
        'writing back to the cells from the array

    Next j 'next row
Next i     'next column

End Sub
```

Assuming that The table starts at column "A", making column "R" the 18th column.

Or, you could loop through the columns, and clear the ones that you don't want:

```
Dim tblArray As Variant, col as Variant
Set tblArray = tbl.ListColumns        'Array of all columns

For Each col In tblArray              'looping through the columns
    If Not col.Name = "Column18" And Not col.Name = "Column19" Then 'checking the headers
        tbl.ListColumns(col.Name).DataBodyRange.ClearContents 'Instead of tbl.DataBodyRange.ClearContents
    End If
Next col
```

Giving them the proper Headline names ofc.